# Default syntax highlighting for [CUDA] questions

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Could you set the default syntax highlighting for [cuda](/questions/tagged/cuda) questions to C++?  (unless they contain the [fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran) or its synonyms)?

Reading through large chucks of poorly formatted code is marginally easier when the syntax highlighting is enabled. But [Most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557051) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512118)  [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522529) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511714) [highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376153) [enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245070).

There are [1004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda) questions tagged with [cuda](/questions/tagged/cuda). That said:

Only [11 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda+fortran) are flagged with [cuda](/questions/tagged/cuda) + [fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran)

[134 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda+c) are flagged with [cuda](/questions/tagged/cuda)+[c](/questions/tagged/c)

[193 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda%20c%2b%2b) are flagged with [cuda](/questions/tagged/cuda)+[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Comment: It would be interesting to see what happens when two tags are associated to two different highlighting modes, and see which one has the priority.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: neither. If two tags on a question both have a highlighting syntax defined, the highlighter defaults to autodetect.

Comment: I would think that the CUDA questions I linked to would be auto-detected, but there is no syntax-highlighting. (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511714) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245070) <-- and both appear to be pretty standard C++ )

Comment: Thank you to whom ever just turned that on!!  :O)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set the language to "default" (auto-detect - should result in reasonable highlighting for C-like code) for [cuda](/questions/tagged/cuda). That shouldn't interfere with anything important (you'll get highlighting now for things like stack traces if you use a code block for them, but that's pretty common anyway - prefix them with `<!-- language: lang-none -->` if you care).

FWIW, there's no highlighting available for FORTRAN. So the results of cuda+fortran code blocks are a little... interesting. Again, it can be turned off on a per-block basis if necessary.

Comment: Again, thanks!  This looks much better!