# Integrate Java code highlighting into the JUnit tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

I have seen many questions on Stackoverflow with the [junit](/questions/tagged/junit) tag but without the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag. As a result the code was not highlighted, because of the missing code-tag. I would like to see the Java-code highlighting implemented as a *default* into the [junit](/questions/tagged/junit) tag, so the code gets highlighted even without the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag to Java **unless** an other laguage-tag is provided.

Although the [junit](/questions/tagged/junit) tag could be used by *Scala* code this is in less than 1% the case and the default is *Java*.

This was done for [cuda](/questions/tagged/cuda) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)-highlight although CUDA can be used by other program languages with wrappers. Compare  [Default syntax highlighting for [CUDA] questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97297/190805)

Maybe there are other unmistakable tages.

Comment: I've got JUnit tests in Scala.  It's not *always* guaranteed to be Java.

Comment: In such cases, you should always pair the tag with the appropriate language tag.

Comment: It's my point then that one can't assume that JUnit exclusively refers to Java.  There may be some unmistakable tags, but this is one of those cases in which a hole in logic is observed.

Comment: You can always enforce highlighting with language hints, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/167534

Comment: this request if for the users, which forget to add the laguage-tag

Comment: Then you should just add the tag whenever you see it. There isn't much you can automatically do for people who aren't tagging properly.

Comment: To add some numbers to this discussion: of the [3,883 questions currently tagged JUnit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/junit) fully [40% are not tagged java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/junit+-java). (I don't have any numbers for how many are tagged, e.g., Scala.)

Answer (score 3):

JUnit was originally developed for Java, so I don't think auto-tagging with `lang-java` would be inappropriate. The JUnit website doesn't even mention the word Scala, if my [Google-fu](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Ajunit.org+scala) is accurate.

I also believe that those using Scala are more adjusted to the idea that Java technologies can work with Scala. By contrast, many Java programmers will be unfamiliar with Scala and wouldn't know the distinction is required.

Whatever is decided, I've [edited the junit tag excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1178445) to suggest the corresponding language tag is added.

---

To continue with the numbers started by [blahdiblah](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137004/blahdiblah) in the comments (as of 16th Dec 2012):

- **Total JUnit questions: 4,402**
- *of which tagged Java:* 2,547 (*58%*)
- *of which tagged Scala:* 31 (*0.7%*)
- *not tagged Java or Scala:* 1,831 (*42%*)

Considering only the tagged questions, then 98.7% of all JUnit questions are Java-related. And note, this figure is likely to be corrupt in favour of Scala - Scala users are *very* likely to tag their questions appropriately because they are aware readers will assume they are using Java.

I think a language hint that suits at *least* 98% of the questions asked is quite appropriate. Especially when the minority group are more likely to tag their questions appropriately.

Comment: I disagree. JUnit is a framework based on the JRE and therefor language agnostic. Adding a language hint to it is as inappropriate as adding a language hint to `[.net]` (for C#).

Answer (score 2):

If it has to do with java, you should retag it (via suggested edit if you don't have the rep) with [java](/questions/tagged/java). [You can also add `<!-- language: lang-java -->` above the code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/172958). While you're at it, add the [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) tags to the appropriate ones.

Comment: I know how to do this. Bu wouldn't it be easier if I don't have to retag every 5th [tag:JUnit]-Question?